# android send several parameter with retrofit

Tags: android, gson, httprequest, retrofit2

I want to send several parameter to server with retrofit but every time I do this I get error.

error title:
com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $

I don not know what is wrong.
this is my codes

java code:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("rating.php")
Call<Message> addComment(@Field("app_id") String appId, @Field("user_id") String userId,@Field("comment_title") String comment,@Field("star") int star);
```

php code:

```
  $message=array();
  $appId=$_POST["app_id"];
  $userId=$_POST["user_id"];
  $title=$_POST["comment_title"];
  $star=$_POST["star"];
  $message["message"]="ok";
  echo json_encode($message);
```

its my Message.java:

```
public class Message {
@SerializedName("message")
public String message;

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String title) {
    this.message = title;
}
```

}

Comment: share your response json and `Message.java`

Comment: you can see message.java

Comment: Your PHP is returning a list, not an object

Comment: its return an object like this:{"message":"ok"}

Answer (score 0):

Change your PHP script to get right JSON response

```
  [{"message":"ok"}]

  <?php
  $appId=$_POST["app_id"];
  $userId=$_POST["user_id"];
  $title=$_POST["comment_title"];
  $star=$_POST["star"];
  $message["message"]="ok";

  header('Content-Type: application/json; Accept-Charset: utf-8; ');
  $response = array();
  array_push($response, $message);
  echo json_encode($response);
  ?>
```

Comment: message is a json object ,I dont need a json array

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry ,I made a mistake I send a null variable to server and server doesnt know that so return me an error,thank you guys